# How to display Timer with day, hour etc

Tags: c#, timer, win-universal-app

I'm trying to create a `Timer` which records the users 'Time Played' as you can expect the `Timer` should be ticking every second. I want it to be displayed as:

**0d 12h 11m 23s**

This is what I have so far:

```
private void TimePlayedTimer_Start()
{ 
  timePlayedStr = "00:00:00:00";       
  timePlayed = new DispatcherTimer();
  timePlayed.Tick += timePlayedTimer_Tick;
  timePlayed.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1);
  timePlayed.Start();
}
```

`timePlayedStr` is what is retrieved from the `localStorage` but in this example I have just set it to `"00:00:00:00"` to make it easier to understand

Then I have a `tick` event:

```
void timePlayedTimer_Tick(object sender, object e)
{
  DateTime newDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(timePlayedStr).AddSeconds(1);
  string newDateTimeStr = newDateTime .ToString("dd:HH:mm:ss");
}
```

So I basically want it to add a second every `tick` then when it gets to 60 seconds it'll add a minute, then hour then day, but then I want it displayed like:

**0d 12h 11m 23s**

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: why are you doing `Convert.ToDateTime(timePlayedStr)`? instead of creating a property of type `DateTime`?

Comment: Wouldn't it be much simpler to record the time they started playing, and subtract that from the current time?

Comment: @JensHorstmann It's retrieved initially as a `string` :(

Comment: @JeffUK But then it wouldn't record the time they have actually played, it would just record how long ago they started playing.. like I want it where when you go on the app, thats when the time played increments, rather than incrementing when they're not even playing because that would defeat the purpose of time played

Comment: you retrieved "00:00:00:00".. thats the same like `DateTime time = new DateTime();`

Comment: @JensHorstmann I know, its not actually "00:00:00:00" I said in the question "but in this example I have just set it to "00:00:00:00" to make it easier to understand"

Comment: You could write 'total time played' back to a local variable whenever the app closes;  I'm worried about the performance impacts of calling the 'tick' function every second,  and the accuracy of it (no guaranteed execution.)

Comment: @JeffUK Do you think that the tick every second would have a huge impact on the performance?

Comment: store your application start time, use diff to now and get the elapsed time.
On app close add your elapsed time to the store.

Comment: If you use DateTime as intermediate value, the user shouldn't get past about 30 days of play-time. DateTime is a moment in time, use TimeSpan for durations.

Comment: @HansKesting I still receive the same error?

Comment: DateTime can't handle "day", "month" or "year" components of zero. All three start at 1 (1st of jan, 0001) and have a limited range. What was your input string?

Comment: @HansKesting So it's initially stored as a `string` "00:00:00" how would I convert to `TimeSpan` to add a second every `tick`? to then convert it to 0d 0h 0m 0s format?

Comment: There is a [TimeSpan.Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.parse.aspx) method for that. And the [.ToString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.tostring.aspx) method also accepts format parameters

Comment: @HansKesting One of the problems I'm having is adding a second to the `TimeSpan` I have this so far `TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.Parse(timePlayedStr);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94820/discussion-between-hans-kesting-and-ktov).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display your "time" in the "0d 12h 11m 23s" format, use

```
string newDateTimeStr = newDateTime.ToString("d'd ' H'h ' m'm ' s's'");
```

the parts between the `'` are used verbatim, not interpreted as placeholder.

**EDIT**
When you have a TimeSpan, use this to get to your display format:

```
string displayTimeStr = storedTimespan.ToString(@"d\d\ h\h\ m\m\ s\s");
```

here all non-format characters (including spaces) need to be escaped by a backslash, which itself doesn't need to be escaped because of the @verbatim string.

Comment: Thanks, on this line `DateTime newDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(timePlayedStr).AddSeconds(1);` I get an error, "string is not recognized as DateTime format" Any idea why?

Comment: @KTOV - did you use my *display* string to store your value? You should keep this for display only and store in your old format or update the list of format strings.

Comment: Yup, im still trying to store as dd:hh:mm:ss but i keep getting the error

Answer (score 0):

**Two Steps:** 
**1.**
Save the time when you have started playing.
**2.**
 Create a timer with a update function and substract the actual time with the time started. then you get a TimeSpan which is the time played.

```
using System.Timers;
public class Test
{
    DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    TimeSpan TimePlayed { get; set; }
    Timer Timer { get; set; }

    public Test()
    {
        Timer = new Timer() {Interval = 1000};
        Timer.Elapsed += Update;
        Timer.Start();
        StartTime = DateTime.Now;
    }

    private void Update(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        TimePlayed = DateTime.Now - StartTime;
    }
}
```

For sure you can do `.ToString(...)` and get the format you like -  as you did in your code.

I am no App developer so i don't know how C# works on phone. but if you quit the app you should save the time. a super easy way should be saving the time in a file like this:

```
private const string FileNameAndLocation = "yourfilename.txt";
private void AppClosing()
{
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(FileNameAndLocation))
    {
        sw.WriteLine(StartTime.ToString());
    }
}

private void AppStarting()
{
    if (!File.Exists(FileNameAndLocation))
    {
        StartTime = DateTime.Now;
        return;
    }

    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(FileNameAndLocation))
    {
        var line = sr.ReadLine();
        StartTime = Convert.ToDateTime(line);
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought I explained this in the comment? Okay, perhaps I start the app on `11/11/2015 at 15:00` then I quit the app, and come back onto the app on `12/11/2015 at 15:00` it would say I've played the game for 1 day, even though I had quit the app as soon as the `StartTime` was initialized. Now what I'm trying to achieve is, when I enter the app on `11/11/2015 at 15:00` and quit straight away it should say i've played for `2 seconds` (Depending how long it took to reach that line upon quitting the app) but if i stay on app til `11/11/2015 17:00` it should say time played = 0d 2h 0m 0s

Comment: So your problem is loading the `StartTime` when you have quited the app once? Because i think the other things are implemented as you descriped them.

Comment: Displayed as "0d 12h 11m 23s" and any other alternatives since someone mentioned performance, it now has me worried

Comment: performance is no problem when your timer ticks with 1 second. 1 second is a so big time that it will be very hard to measure the performance lose. your mobile cpu has a clockspeed of over 1 GHz. that means it is able to handle theoretically over 1 billion instructions per second.